# this.name returns undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, element, onload

I am trying to remotely create an `onclick` for each `<div>` (to save typing time).

Here is the `window.onload()` function:

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    divel = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var el in divel) {
      divel[el].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.textDecoration = "underline";
      };
      divel[el].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.textDecoration = "none";
      };
      divel[el].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('game').src = "/games/" + this.name;
      };
    }
  }
```

The name of every `<div>` is `"flyingsheep"` - this value was set by `<div name="flyingsheep">`.

When I click the `<div>`, the iframe `"game"` takes me to the webpage `"/games/undefined"`.

Comment: Does the `for` really alter the meaning of `this`?

Comment: @bzlm — no, and by the time the anonymous functions are called, `for` is long gone.

Comment: FYI, *element.name* is not set for `div`, see [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work. the problem is corrected.

just use : `this.attributes["name"].value`

```
window.onload = function() { 
        divel = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var el in divel){
        window.alert(divel[el].name);
            divel[el].onmouseover = function(){ this.style.textDecoration = "underline"; };
            divel[el].onmouseout = function(){ this.style.textDecoration = "none"; };
            divel[el].onclick = function(){document.getElementById('game').src = this.attributes["name"].value;} 
        }
}
```

Comment: Tested in Firefox 4.0 and IE 8.0

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what the problem is for sure, as I don't have access to your test case so I can't see any errors or try to tweak it to make t work, but some problems are:

`<div name="flyingsheep">` is not traditional, it is invalid. There is [no `name` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) for div elements.

I wouldn't be surprised if the JS was throwing an error when you try to set `divel.length.onmouseover` — don't use `for ( foo in bar )` on array like objects, use a normal counter.

My best theory is that you have more `div` elements then the ones you care about, and it is a click on one of those (one without a name attribute), possibly that contains the one you are aiming to click on) that is firing the JS function.

Comment: As mentioned, this is difficult to debug without a complete test case.

Comment: I said that in my post :). Anyway, the below answer has worked. I didn't know that div doesn't have a name="" value - how stupid is that?

Comment: You did not mention it being hard for people to solve your problem without your HTML at all. I'm very surprised that the above (hint: Stackoverflow lets you sort answers in different ways 'above' and 'below' are meaningless) worked. It is just different syntax for getting the same thing. And it isn't at all stupid, we have `class` a generic non-unique identifier, we don't need another one, leave name for form controls.

Comment: The divs already have classes. Are form controls the only thing that have name attributes?

Comment: The class attribute takes a space separated **list** of classes, so "having a class already" is no reason not to have another one. Frames also have names, to tie in to target (and 'ewugh frames'). Anchors have them, but deprecated in XHTML 1.1. There are a couple of others, the attribute has all sorts of different meanings depending on where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

[In jquery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you could instead use:

```
$(this).attr("name");
```

Comment: It is not worth (performance-wise) loading a massive library just for the use of one function