# Standard-compilant, compatible way to get element name

Tags: javascript, domdocument

In javascript, I would like to get the `name` attribute of an element.

- [The Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.name) says we can use `e.name` or `e.elementName` (the latter gives undefined in Chrome for me)
- [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528617/324969) says to use `e.attributes["name"].value`
- I guess if I tried, I'd find a few more ways.

Which way is standard-compilant ?

Which way is most compatible ?

Where can I get a list of how to access each attribute (for example, `id` can be accessed directly by `e.id`, and I'm pretty sure it's a standard-compliant way to access it) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some degree it depends on the element type. The `name` attribute isn't supported in all element types, so it would depend on if you're using it in a valid way.

To get the value in the broadest way, use `.getAttribute()`.

```
element.getAttribute("name");
```

If you're using `name` on elements that support that attribute, then I'd just use the `.name` property.

```
element.name;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the attribute on form elements, and they do support it (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Yes, the `.name` attribute is supported on form elements, so you should be safe with `.name`.